# What is the meaning of batch size in the background of deep reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, batchsize

Batch size mean the number of samples trained in neural work in supervised learning, however, what is the meaning of batch size meaning in the background of reinforcement learning? Does it refer to samples too? If so, what is the samples meaning in the background of reinforcement learning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batch size does indeed mean the same thing in reinforcement learning, compared to supervised learning.  The intuition of "batch learning" (usually in mini-batch) is two-fold:

1. Due to memory constraints of hardware, it may be difficult to do batch gradient descent on over 1,000,000 data points.
2. To calculate the gradient of loss on an subset of the whole data, that is representative of the whole data.  If the batch you train on at each step is not representative of the whole data, there will be bias in your update step.

In supervised learning, such as neural networks, you would do mini-batch gradient descent to update your neural network.  In deep reinforcement learning, you're training the same neural networks, so it works in the same way.

In supervised learning, your batch would consist of a set of features, and its respective labels.  In deep reinforcement learning, it is similar.  It is a tuple (state, action, reward, state at t + 1, sometimes done).

State: The original state that describes your environment

Action:  The action you performed in that environmental state

Reward:  Reward signal obtained after performing that action in that state

State t+1: The new state your action transitioned you to.

Done: A boolean referring to the end of your task.  For example, if you train RL to play chess, done would be either winning or losing the chess game.

You would sample a batch of these (s, a, r, s(t+1), done) tuples.  Then you feed it into the TD update rule, usually in the form of:

[image]

The two Q's are the action values, and are calculated by passing s, s(t+1) and a into your neural network.

Then, you would update your neural network with the Q as the label.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, if the batch size is 150, in the background of deep reinforcement learning, the meaning is trained with 150 tuples? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, and ideally, those samples should be distributed in a way that is representative of the whole problem so you don't run into bias issues.

Comment: Does the batch size only apply on the Q learning? Does it still represent the same thing in policy gradient method, such as trust region policy gradient?

Comment: The general idea does.  the method holds for any RL methods that have batch learning.  For sample efficiency, some people do it even for tabular RL where at each step, they do a batch update.  For policy gradients, I believe you have to first discount the rewards back in time at the end of each episode, and create your tuples that way.  Because policy gradients are trained using monte carlo simulation.  But in the end, you'll still get a tuple of the 5 things listed above.  For the 2nd method, do you mean trust region policy optimization?  Either way, they should be the same  / similar.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help